# Negative short in Java to uint16_t in NDK not handled correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I'm puzzled by behavior I'm seeing with the Android NDK regarding negative shorts as parameters. I've reduced it to a simple example.

I have the following c function:

```
void shortTest(uint16_t input)
{
    uint16_t tmp = -1;
    LogInfo("shortTest input: 0x%X\n", input); // wrapper for logging
    LogInfo("shortTest tmp: 0x%X\n", tmp);
}
```

The corresponding Java signature:

```
void shortTest(short input);
```

The function is called like this:

```
short s = -1;
MyLibrary.INSTANCE.shortTest(s);
```

The output:

```
INFO   : 21:10:01:158 - shortTest:6158: shortTest input: 0xFFFFFFFF
INFO   : 21:10:01:158 - shortTest:6159: shortTest tmp: 0xFFFF
```

This behavior can cause failures, for example with comparisons (input is not equal to tmp). As a work-around I just changed the c function to take a uint32_t and pass in an int. However, I'm concerned about this biting me in other areas as I use uint16's pretty regularly. It seems to somehow force the storage type from 2 bytes to 4. Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java `short` is signed, so you're sort of lying to the compiler about what `shortTest` will receive.

Let's consider the consequences of this by looking at the following C code and its corresponding ARM assembly:

```
// Here I'm using int16_t, because that's basically what you've declared that
// you will pass to shortTest from your Java code.
void shortTest(int16_t input) {
    printf("shortTest input: 0x%X\n", input);
}

int main() {
    shortTest(-1);
}

shortTest:
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, lr}
    mov     r1, r0              @ Just pass on input as the second argument to printf
    movw    r0, #:lower16:.LC0  @ Load string address
    movt    r0, #:upper16:.LC0  @ ...
    bl      printf              @ Call printf
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, pc}       @ Return


main:
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, lr}
    mvn     r0, #0         @ First argument = 0xFFFFFFFF
    bl      shortTest      @ Call shortTest
    mov     r0, #0         @ Value to return from main
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, pc}  @ Return
```

My `main` here would be your Java code, so it's passing `0xFFFFFFFF` to `shortTest`, which is fine because for all it knows `shortTest` wants a signed short. Then you arrive at `shortTest` which (in your case) thinks it received an unsigned short, but it assumes that the caller passed the right kind of value so it won't do any zero-extention.

Then you try to print this value, and if your logging function works like `printf`/`sprintf` it will implicitly promote your `short` to an `int`, i.e. it will print a 32-bit value (excluding leading zeroes). And the 32-bit value in this case is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So a short in Java is 32 bits? I would expect Java to pass 0xFFFF instead of 0xFFFFFFFF.

I also don

Comment: continued:
Also, it seems according to the ISO C standard, casting a value outside of the valid values is undefined. However, I've never seen an instance where the higher order bits were not just discarded. That seems to be not the case here. Casting, assigning to another short, etc. all have no effect and is still treated as 32 bits.

Comment: No, a `short` in Java is signed 16-bits. However, CPU registers on modern CPU architectures are typically 32-bit (or 64-bit), and it may be more efficient on some architectures to load a register with the immediate `0xFFFFFFFF` instead of `0x0000FFFF`. That would not cause any problems if `shortTest` actually wanted a signed 16-bit value, which is what you've said in the Java code. But on the C side you've told the compiler that `shortTest` gets an unsigned 16-bit value, and it will trust you and assume that whatever the caller passed to it is correct.

Comment: Ah, ok. That is the key part I was missing. I'll just continue with using an #ifdef to define the parameter as 32 bits for Android. (though in theory I could also define as an int16, I'll probably try that). Thanks!